# javascript object: convert comma separated object (number) back into list of arrays

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

for example, now I have

`player: {id: 1, name: "jack", selected_scenarios: "[369,368]"}` in the local storage.

within here `[369,368]` is a javascript object with length of 7.

If I want to convert it into list of array, pull numbers out such that
`electedArray = [369,368]` has length of 2, which can be read by `electedArray[i]`

```
0: 369

1: 368
```

how am I supposed to do so?

If I did

```
let test = res["player"]["selected_scenarios"];
let selectedArray = [];
for (var prop in test) {
  selectedArray.push(test[prop])
}
console.log(selectedArray);
```

I got
 `["[", "3", "6", "9", ",", "3", "6", "8", "]"]`
and split doesn't seem to work neither.

I know it looks like lots of similar questions around, but I still can't figure out how

Comment: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: oh I am so dumb

Comment: We've all done it... :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
 You can do something like it:

```js
let test = res["player"]["selected_scenarios"];
let selectedArray =  JSON.parse(test);

console.log(selectedArray);
```

And then you have access to your array and your array will be like this:

```js
[369, 368]
```

Comment: I'm so dumb after staying up 36 hours.. thanks!

Comment: you're welcome friend